# Convert numbers to letters

Tags: string, r, replace, gsub

I have the following vector:

```
x <- c(11, 12, 21, 22)
```

And I want to convert it to the corresponding letters, i.e., I want to get this result:

```
AA AB BA BB
```

How do I make this? I bet there's a simple answer and that it goes through using the reserved `LETTERS` vector, but I can't figure out a solution. This is the best I've managed to come up with so far (you might want to take the kids out of the room):

```
> paste0(gsub(1, LETTERS[1], substr(x, 1, 1)),
         gsub(2, LETTERS[2], substr(x, 1, 1)))
[1] "A1" "A1" "2B" "2B"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since this just involves one-to-one character substitution, it might be simplest to just use `chartr()`

```
chartr("123456789", "ABCDEFGHI", x)
# [1] "AA" "AB" "BA" "BB"
```

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
x <- c(11, 12, 21, 22)

s1 = as.numeric(substr(x, start=1, stop=1))
s2 = as.numeric(substr(x, start=2, stop=2))

print(paste0(LETTERS[s1], LETTERS[s2]))

>[1] "AA" "AB" "BA" "BB"
```

Answer (score 5):

Without libraries, the compact one-line solution is

```
sapply(strsplit(paste(x),''), function(y) paste(LETTERS[as.numeric(y)], collapse = ''))
# [1] "AA" "AB" "BA" "BB"
```

Comment: Nice one, but keep in mind that when this will be faced with a zero it will return the empty character thus rendering 1 and 10 both as "A".

Answer (score 2):

or like this:

```
sapply(strsplit(as.character(c(123,11,22,5612)),""), function(x) paste0(LETTERS[as.integer(x)], collapse=""))
    ## [1] "ABC"  "AA"   "BB"   "EFAB"
```